# О происхождении названий "Хотецкое" и "Хотемля".

Tags: названия, этимология

Существует селение под названием "Хотецкое" на берегу живописного озера "Хотемля". Хотелось бы выслушать ваши версии, уважаемые профессионалы и любители русского языка, по поводу происхождения этих названий. Интересно было бы так же понять, какое из этих названий явилось прообразом: "Хотецкое" для "Хотемли", либо же, наоборот. Примечание: В слове "ХотЕцкое" ударение падает на второй слог, а в "ХотемлЯ" - на последний.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно  гидронимы  древнее  названий  населённых  пунктов, возникших  на  их  берегах.  Да  на  слух  слово  Хотемля  не  славянское.  Финское,  наверное.